# @react-native-firebase/auth: app not authorized Error in signInWithPhoneNumber

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to set up a react-native project with firebase to **signInWithPhoneNumber** functionality. I am receiving an error:

> NativeFirebaseError: [auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed. Is app running on a physical device? ]

My Function call is as follows:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

Screen Class
....
getOtp = async () => {

....
auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(`+91${phonenumber}`)
      .then(confirmResult =>
      ....
}
```

I have tried all the setup instructions for the Firebase connection.

The Steps I have tried are:

- I have the same package name in the react-native android project and firebase console.
- Added the SHA1 from signingReport to Firebase Console.
- Copied the google-services.json to android/app Folder.
- Linked the Firebase to Android Studio via Google Analytics.

Giving Dummy Mobile Number for Testing works and has no issue but not with actual mobile number.
In android studio debugger, I am getting error issue displaying:

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@8b3312c

D/Auth: signInWithPhoneNumber:verification:failed
```

package details in package.json:

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.3.3",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
```

config in build.gradle(app):

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
    //implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2"

}
...
```

config in build.gradle(projectname):

```
...
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        // googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
...
```

Comment: If it's not working after downloaded from google play store. So it's regarding double sha-1 generation. you need to copy SHA-1 from google play console account and add it into your firebase account. In this scenario it could be.

Answer (score 2):

I think in order to prevent abuse the firebase phone authentication wont work in emulator. It only works with real device.

**But if you want it for testing purpose then you should add use some testing phone number in firebase console that will work in emulator.**

Go to your firebase console -> Authentication -> SIGN-IN Method -> Phone and check the "Phone numbers for testing (optional)" field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In your root app folder, run `keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/app/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
2. Copy the returned SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys to the firebase console
3. Download the new `google-services.json` file in `./android/app`

Comment: somehow It works! but actually, do I need to run `./gradlew signingReport` again ?
`